# Autohotkey: Don't activate multiple triggers

Tags: autohotkey

In Autohotkey, I have two Hotkeys:

```
1) #\::  (Win + \)
2) #^\:: (Win + Ctrl + \)
```

If I press Win + \, both triggers are activated. How can I make them mutually exclusive?

Comment: What are the actions associated with the hotkeys? Because if you press just Win + \ and the second one is fired then the first hotkey must something do to fulfill the requirement of pressing CTRL

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it. Embarassing..

I forgot to include a "Return" at the end of each triggered action.